# Send static image when video is muted in pjSIP Android

Tags: android, pjsip

I am developing an application using pjSIP JNI APIs. In this application, I need to cater a use case when video is muted (don't use Camera2), but need to send some still image to peer.
I did not find any pjSIP JNI interface through which I can do it.
Any help is greatly appreciated.

pjSIP android JNI APIs & stack overflow

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: You need to handle this on the UI side.